# How to print out multiple responses from service

Tags: ros, tutorial, print, rosservice, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently trying to create a service which can send multiple responses. I edited the tutorial service ( http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29 ) to:

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
int64 multi
```

multi = a * b

in another question (https://answers.ros.org/question/381207/create-a-service-with-multiple-responses/) somebody already helped me to adjust the server.py but so far I'm not able to print out sum and multi this is my attempt so far
client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import rospy
from service_node.srv import *

def add_two_ints_client(x, y):
    rospy.wait_for_service('add_two_ints')
    try:
        add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
        resp1 = add_two_ints(x, y)
        return resp1
    except rospy.ServiceException as e:
        print("Service call failed: %s"%e)

def usage():
    return "%s [x y]"%sys.argv[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        x = int(sys.argv[1])
        y = int(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        print(usage())
        sys.exit(1)
    print("Requesting %s+%s"%(x, y))
    resp = add_two_ints_client(x, y)
    print(resp)
```

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 
from __future__ import print_function
 
from service_node.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTwoIntsResponse
import rospy
 
def handle_add_two_ints(req):
    print("Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b)))
    return AddTwoIntsResponse(sum(req.a + req.b), multi=(req.a * req.b))
 
def add_two_ints_server():
    rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
    s = rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
    print("Ready to add two ints.")
    rospy.spin()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_two_ints_server()
```

output:

```
Requesting 5+1
Service call failed: service [/add_two_ints] responded with an error: b"error processing request: 'int' object is not iterable"
None
```

System:
ROS noetic, Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3

```
Traceback from the server:
[ERROR] [1624971980.654584]: Error processing request: multi is not an attribute of AddTwoIntsResponse
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 632, in _handle_request\n    response = convert_return_to_response(self.handler(request), self.response_class)\n', '  File "/home/fabi/catkin_ws/src/service_node/scripts/server.py", line 10, in handle_add_two_ints\n    return AddTwoIntsResponse(sum=(req.a + req.b), multi=(req.a * req.b))\n', '  File "/home/fabi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/service_node/srv/_AddTwoInts.py", line 154, in __init__\n    super(AddTwoIntsResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)\n', '  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 361, in __init__\n    raise AttributeError(\'%s is not an attribute of %s\' % (k, self.__class__.__name__))\n', 'AttributeError: multi is not an attribute of AddTwoIntsResponse\n']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381297/how-to-print-out-multiple-responses-from-service/) by [Verismoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/76721/verismoto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a traceback printed by the server?

Can you call your service from the command line (ie: with `rosservice call ...`)?

---

Edit: this line could be problematic:

> ```
> print("Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b)))
> ```

If you change all `%s` to `%d`, does it stop complaining?

---

Edit 2: I don't believe this is completely correct:

> ```
> return AddTwoIntsResponse(sum(req.a + req.b), multi=(req.a * req.b))
> ```

Note the `sum(req.a + req.b)`. That should be `sum=(req.a + req.b)`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Verismoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/76721/verismoto/) on 2021-06-29**:
I added the traceback to my question. Multi seems to be not an attribute of AddTwoIntsResponse.
I also fixed the `sum = (req.a +req.b)` now the output is:

```
Requesting 5+1
Service call failed: service [/add_two_ints] responded with an error: b'error processing request: multi is not an attribute of AddTwoIntsResponse'
None
```

Changing from %s to %d also had no impact
And I can't call the service with `rosservice call` but `rossrv show service_node/AddTwoInts` works

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-29**:\

> Multi seems to be not an attribute of AddTwoIntsResponse.

then it would suggest that the changes you've made to the service definition have not been consistently applied everywhere.

> but `rossrv show service_node/AddTwoInts` works

and what does that show?

**Comment by [Verismoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/76721/verismoto/) on 2021-06-29**:
after running `catkin_make` again the output is now

```
rosrun service_node client.py 5 1
Requesting 5+1
sum: 6
multi: 5
```

so the service is now working, but multi has the wrong result

`rossrv show service_node/AddTwoInts` shows the correct .srv file

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
int64 multi
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-29**:\

> but multi has the wrong result

how is `5` wrong? `5*1==5`, is it not?

**Comment by [Verismoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/76721/verismoto/) on 2021-06-29**:
oh you are right sorry, i always tested with 5 * 2 before now it finally works
thanks alot